# Spring Security restricting access to certain roles at certain url levels

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to understand Spring Security and I have a page that asks you to login at startup and then the user has a role. I'm trying to say that all roles can access the welcome page, but if you want to login to the admin page then you can only be either an EMPLOYEE or a USER.

Here is the configure method:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").hasAnyRole("EMPLOYEE", "USER","NONE1")
        
                .antMatchers("/courierapp/admin").hasAnyRole("EMPLOYEE","USER")
        
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and().formLogin();     
    }
```

Why is it that /courierapp/admin is still able to be accessed if I have a role of "NONE1" for example?

Comment: As long as you have any of the other roles you are allowed access.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm not following what you're saying. This user only has NONE1 and accesses admin even though it is not an employee or a user. Why is that possible? Am I doing the syntax wrong?

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question. Also if `/courierapp` is the name of the app (or the base) your URL should be `/admin` which would make the first `/*` match and you would need to reverse the order.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having an issue with Spring Security using antMatchers, it is first one matches so in this case I had to do:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasAnyRole("EMPLOYEE","USER")
                .antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole("EMPLOYEE", "USER","NONE1")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin(); 
    }
```

This makes it so only employees and users will be able to access /admin. Also, if there is a base path in your url and you don't know where it's coming from, that's just the root path.

Comment: In this case that wouldn't matter. However `/courierapp/admin` and `/admin` are quite different URLs to match.